# How do I make button to align with input in form-horizontal in bootstrap3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<form action="/" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<div id="div_id_text_input" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_text_input" class="control-label col-md-2">
     Text input<span class="asteriskField">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls col-md-4">
        <input class="input-xlarge textinput textInput form-control" 
               id="id_text_input" name="text_input" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_textarea" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_textarea" class="control-label 
           col-md-2 requiredField">Textarea
    </label>
    <div class="controls col-md-4">
        <textarea class="input-xlarge textarea form-control" cols="40" 
                  id="id_textarea" name="textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
    <input type="submit" name="save_changes" value="Save changes" 
           class="btn btn-primary btn-primary" id="submit-id-save_changes" />
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" 
           id="submit-id-cancel" />
</div>
```

The form action button is left aligned with labels by default. 
How could I make it to align with inputs.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flyingfoxlee/Qt2Cf/)

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/flyingfoxlee/Qt2Cf/embedded/result/)

Comment: Use `.col-offset-md-2` to offset the form-action div

Comment: @JoelCornett It has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label"></label> <!-- Add this line -->
    <input type="submit" name="save_changes" value="Save changes" 
       class="btn btn-primary btn-primary" id="submit-id-save_changes" />
```

[Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/akki06/7zAfE/embedded/result/)

Comment: If that is what you want to do.

Comment: Glad I could help.Please close the question.

Comment: One more question though, the `button` is not strictly aligned on the left, there is a blank space there. I think it's the blank between the label and button. Any suggestion to get rid of it?

Comment: I see it fine. 
Can you clarify a bit, maybe I am looking wrong.

Comment: It happens when the width is small, but I think it's better than without space. Thank you.